# Include a xyz.framework file with cocoapod spec

Tags: swift, frameworks, static-libraries, cocoapods

This is a quick questions about the cocoapod.. I am trying to build a cocoapod which has all my files and dependencies however I have some libraries in form of .framework which I include in my project.

How can I put them in my project so that, when a user install my pod, that .framework will also be available to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how to do this by looking at another cocoapod's podspec and going to the source download link. I will use my cocoapod "BeaconsInSpace" as an example. The podspec can be found [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/BeaconsInSpace/1.0.4/BeaconsInSpace.podspec.json).

Go to the link specified as the source. This will download the cocoapod. Now that you have it downloaded you can see the folder structure. You need to set your "preserve_paths" in your podspec as the folders or files you want users of you pod to access. In this example case I just did the top level folder. Next you want to set "vendored_frameworks" to be the exact path to your framework within your folder structure. You can use this example podspec as a guide. You can also just Google any cocoapod's podspec to see how the creators of your favorite pods have set up their specs. All the specs are publicly available.

Answer (score 2):

Add it in vendored_frameworks

```
spec.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/xyz.framework'
```

where

> 'Frameworks/xyz.framework'

is path for that framework

Comment: I too got it....thanks for this support and if anything goes wrong, I will get back...